# Interpreting the rfImpute() output in the randomForest R package - meaning of columns named 1 and 2

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, imputation

What is the meaning of the output of columns named 1, 2 and 3 when using `rfImpute()` in the R package `randomForest`?

I have checked the documentation and it only explains the output of the ntree and OOB columns, but not the columns 1, 2, and 3. What do these % values reflect?

Here is an example:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
iris.na <- iris

# Artificially drop some data values.
set.seed(100)
for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA


# Impute missing data
set.seed(100)
iris.imputed <- rfImpute(Species ~ ., iris.na, iter=6, ntree=500)
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    4.67%  0.00%  6.00%  8.00%
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    5.33%  0.00%  8.00%  8.00%
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    5.33%  0.00%  8.00%  8.00%
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    6.00%  0.00%  8.00% 10.00%
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    4.67%  0.00%  8.00%  6.00%
#   ntree      OOB      1      2      3
#    500:    4.67%  0.00%  8.00%  6.00%
```